# Upload multiple pictures to server iOS Fastly as Facebook

Tags: php, ios, iphone, performance, image-uploading

We created an App that can upload multiple images to server (PHP REST API), But it takes more time to upload, If i add 10 images to queue then the App is slowly responding

We see that the Facebook iOS app can easily upload multiple images (it tried 32) and they uploaded within 15 seconds

How they managed to upload the pictures to server that fast and how they managed it in the app phone memory

Are they decrease the quality before uploading it to server?

**Specifications of the Server and App:**

xCode: 7.3

Alamofire for Uploading Images [Multipart] - API Calls

PHP: 5.5.9-1

Apache2: 2.4.7

MySQL: 5.5.49-0

**PHP Configuration:**

memory_limit: 512M

max_file_uploads: 100

post_max_size: 512M

max_execution_time: 600

upload_max_filesize: 512M

Image Uploading Code

```
manager.upload(.POST, CustomizedEP,
                   multipartFormData: { multipartFormData in
                    if let imageData = UIImageJPEGRepresentation(profilePic, 1) {
                        multipartFormData.appendBodyPart(data: imageData, name: "temp_pic", fileName: imageName, mimeType: "image/png")
                    }
                    for (key, value) in ["image_name": imageName] {
                        multipartFormData.appendBodyPart(data: value.dataUsingEncoding(NSUTF8StringEncoding)!, name: key as! String)
                    }
        },
                   encodingCompletion: { encodingResult in
                    switch encodingResult {
                    case .Success(let upload, _, _):
                        upload.responseJSON { response in
                            if let data = response.result.value {
                                self.delegate.addPicToPostResponse!(data, Status: (response.response?.statusCode)!);
                                hideLoader(LoaderType.Default);
                            }
                        }
                        upload.progress{ _, totalBytesRead, totalBytesExpectedToRead in
                            //let progress = Float(totalBytesRead)/Float(totalBytesExpectedToRead);
                            //self.delegate.uploadTempPicProgressInfo!(progress, index: index, request: upload.request!); //Removed index so we are not using it
                        }
                    case .Failure(let encodingError):
                        print(encodingError)
                        hideLoader(LoaderType.Default);
                    }
    });
```

We are uploading the images that are taken by iPhone5

Comment: Please show us your code and the images that were uploaded during the tests.

Comment: @RobertColumbia added the code please check

Answer (score 0):

[That's how](http://www.datacenterknowledge.com/the-facebook-data-center-faq/)

However you can just upgrade your server configuration regarding to cpu/memory/datacenter geolocation and internet connection bandwidth

Comment: i don't want the exact responsiveness like facebook, i would like know the logic or architecture how they managed to upload multiple pictures without losing the responsiveness of the app